# Не работает ссылка, выдавая NoReverseMatchError

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-urls

```
NoReverseMatch at /category/1/
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Такая ошибка выводится при переходе на категорию сайта c главной страницы.
Погуглив, узнал что мой url не соответствует с url в шаблоне и django сообщает об этом. Но мне так и не понятно, в чем некорректность, ведь все написано с соответствием к urls.py шаблонам.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('category/<int:category_id>/', get_category, name='category'),
    path('news/<slug:slug>', view_news, name='news'),
]
```

base.html(ссылки из шапки)

```
{% for category in categoies %}
              <li><a href="{% url 'category' category.id %}" class="nav-link px-2" style="color: rgb(179, 179, 179);">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

index.html(главная страница(ссылка из шапки статьи, тоже не рабочая))

```
{% for item in page_obj %}
    <div class="card mb-5">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="category_name"> <a href="{% url 'category' item.category_id %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(93, 92, 92);">{{ item.category }}</a> - {{ item.created_at }}</div>
      </div>
      <a href="/news/{{ item.slug }}" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(26, 25, 25);">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</h3>
          <p class="card-text">{{ item.content|linebreaks|truncatewords:50 }}</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

category.py

```
{% get_all_categories as categoies %}
            {% for category in categoies %}
                {% if category == news.category %}
                  <li><a href="{% url 'category' category_id=category.pk %}" class="nav-link px-2" style="color: white;display: inline; padding: 17px 6px; border-bottom: solid 5px #707990;">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                  <li><a href="{% url 'category' category_id=category.pk %}" class="nav-link px-2" style="display: inline; padding: 0px 6px;">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def home_page(request):
              all_publicated_blogs = News.objects.filter(is_published=True,)

              return render(request, 'news/index.html', 
                                    {'page_obj': Pagination(request,all_publicated_blogs).pagination(10),})


def get_category(request, category_id):
                 news_by_category = News.objects.filter(category_id=category_id, 
                                                        is_published=True)
                 one_news = news_by_category[0]
                 return render(request, 'news/category.html', 
                 {'page_obj': Pagination(request, news_by_category).pagination(10), 
                  'news':one_news,})
```

models.py

```
class News(models.Model):

           title = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Заголовок',)
           content = RichTextField()
           created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name='Дата Создания')
           updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
           is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Опубликовано')                    
           category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, 
                                                    verbose_name='Категория')
           slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', max_length=40, unique=True,)

class Category(models.Model):
           title = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True,
                                    verbose_name='Название категории')
```

news_tags.py

```
from django import template
from news.models import Category


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def get_all_categories():
    return Category.objects.all()
```

Comment: Получается при переходе на url с именем category у вас возникает NoReverseMatchError?

Comment: Да, именно так во всех файлах

Comment: Вероятно, какая-то из новостей у вас не содержит категории, и вы пытаетесь вывести ссылку на никакую категорию

Comment: нет, у меня все новости содержат категории, я проверил

Comment: а если category.id в базовом шаблоне заменить на category_id?

Comment: Тоже не получается